# Getting data from nested JSON object !!WITH ID'S!! using angular GET

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Im kinda new to Angular/ JSON Objects and i'm trying to get something from a nested object.

That is not so hard, but the problem is that the JSON object has an that changes on the fly.

Below an example of 1 object from a complete list of JSON objects. As you can see this part of a larger object.

What i want is the task.assignment.name for each task in the ng-repeat, but i cant get to the assignment.name because of the integer that's between the assignment and name.

> Look at my object:

```
{
"project-45": {
    "label": "Bar",
    "url": "http://someurl.com/api",
    "assignments": {
      "5147": {
         "id": 5147,
         "type": "Task",
         "project_id": 45,
         "assignee_id": 9,
         "label_id": 27,
         "category_id": 0,
         "milestone_id": 0,
         "name": "assignmentname",
         "body": "<p>body.</p>",
         "created_on": "2015-06-17 13:40:31",
         "age": 6,
         "created_by_id": 66,
         "created_by_name": "Jelle",
         "created_by_email": "jelle@example.com",
         "due_on": "2015-06-19",
         "priority": 0,
         "task_id": 81,
         "project": "Bar"
         }
      }
   }
}
project-75": {
    "label": "Another",
    "url": "http://mijn.example.com/api",
    "assignments": {
        "5153":
...
```

> This is my controller:

```
var main = angular.module("main", []);

    main.controller("mainCntrl", function($scope, $http){

        var apiUrl = "http://my.example.com/api.php?&format=json&";
        var apiKey = "&auth_api_token=somekey";

        var onUserComplete = function(response){
            $scope.user = response.data;
            console.log("User Data loaded");
        }

        var onTasksComplete = function(response){
            $scope.tasks = response.data;
            console.log("Tasks loaded");
        }

        $http.get(apiUrl + "path=my-tasks" + apiKey).then(onTasksComplete);
        $http.get(apiUrl + "path=people/1/users/9" + apiKey).then(onUserComplete);

    }
);
```

> and finally the index.html file with the ng-reapter

```
<div class=" block full border">
    <h3>Active tasks</h3>
    <ul ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>{{$index+1}}</li>
                <li>Project: {{task.label}}</li>
                <li>task name: {{task.assignments.name}}</li> <!-- Doesnt work -->
                <li>task description: {{task.assignments.body}}</li> <!-- Doesnt work -->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note about JSON vs objects: JSON is a string and not an object hence its abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have is colloquially referred to as a POJO or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avaScript **O**bject. They are different. The former is a data exchange format similar to YAML or XML while the latter is an actual object with properties and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class=" block full border">
    <h3>Active tasks</h3>
    <ul ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <li>
            <ul ng-repeat="assignment in task.assignments">
                <li>{{$index+1}}</li>
                <li>Project: {{assignment.label}}</li>
                <li>task name: {{assignment.name}}</li> <!-- Doesnt work -->
                <li>task description: {{assignment.body}}</li> <!-- Doesnt work -->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats the thing with Angular. I keep thinking is more complex than it really is :)